# Test OSX App on Yosemite from ElCapitan

Tags: xcode, macos, osx-yosemite, osx-elcapitan

I have developed an OSX for 10.10 and above. This app works with a device in which whenever I connect device and perform some operation, the data on device gets updated on the server. This works fine on El Capitan but one of our client has mentioned an issue on Yosemite, but I've update my Mac from OS X Yosemite 10.10.4 to OS X El Capitan 10.11.1 recently. I've heard that Xcode scheme can be used to define targets for build, but I'm not much aware of using schemes. Is there anyway to simulate Yosemite on El Capitan for testing? Is there anyway to do this through Xcode?

Comment: Not really, version compatibility issues are notoriously hard to test without access to the OS that has the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can choose the **Deployment Target** in the project settings:

[image: Screen Shot]

However, it's **not** 100% reliable even if 10.10 SDK was used to compile on 10.11.

Some XIB files produced on 10.11 in Xcode were sometimes not compatible with 10.10 and not detectable when testing on 10.11, but will crash on 10.10.

e.g. When I use 10.9 SDK to compile a project on 10.10  result in crashes when the NIB files get loaded on 10.9. Some other 10.10 users reported crashes running 10.11 compiled binaries for unknown reason...etc.

To be sure it's 100% working, you should consider **setup virtual machines of older versions of OS X**.